# Minimal boundary conditions for divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've noticed that some domain conditions of questions here were only supposed to be finite dimensional and bounded. And then the divergence theorem was applied in the answers. But if I'm not mistaken, the divergence theorem could be applied if the boundary of the domain fulfills some regularity conditions. One can always construct some very irregular boundaries, e.g. with help of the Weierstrass function, and the domain is although still compact. Can the divergence theorem also be applied for these domains?

Comment: You have to be able to integrate over the boundary in the divergence theorem. How would you do this if the boundary is nowhere smooth?

Comment: @LukasGeyer Yes, I just saw that most conditions about the domain are only bounded and open, and I am not sure if such conditions are enough for applying the divergence theorem.